# I need help finishing this bioinformatics program

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta, blast

I need to create a program that can take some text file called a fasta file and transform it to give the sequence_name, Domain_names, Start of Domain, end Of Domain.

So a fasta file is just a text file that looks like this

```
>MICE_8
ATTCGATCGATCGATTTCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGGATCGATCGATCGATCGATC
>MICE_59 
ATTTTTCGGCATCGATAGCTAGCTAGCTAG
```

My program needs to take one command argument which is the file name of the fasta and give an output like this:

```
MICE_8 gnl|CDD|256537 819 923 gnl|CDD|260076 111 189 gnl|CDD|260056 4 93                                          
MICE_59
```

here is a decription of the output for more information:

- MICE_8 is the name of the first sequence in the fasta file
- gnl|CDD|256537 is the name of the first protein domain
- 819 this is where the domain stats
- 923 this is where it ends
- gnl|CDD|260076 is the name of the second protein domain for the first sequence                                                                                         and so on it starts at 111 and end at position 189.

Also since the last sequence did not get a hit the program still needs to display the name of the sequence.

OK so here is my code so far and what it outputs so far

```
import sys
import os

fastaname = sys.argv[1]
rpsblastname = "rpsblast.out"

cmd = "rpsblast+ -db /home/bryan/data/cdd/cdd -query %s -outfmt 6 -evalue 0.05 > %s" % (fastaname,rpsblastname)
os.system(cmd)

handle = open(rpsblastname, "r")
seqname = ""
for line in handle:
    linearr = line.split()
    # seqname = linearr [0]
    domain = linearr[1]
    start = linearr[6]
    end = linearr[7]
    # If sequence name is the same as last time, don't print it
    if seqname == linearr[0]:
        sys.stdout.write("%s %s %s" % (domain, start, end))
    # Otherwise do print the sequence name, and update seqname
    else:
        seqname = linearr[0]
        print
        sys.stdout.write("%s %s %s %s" % (seqname,domain,start,end))
```

here is what my output looks like so far:

```
mel@roswald:~$ ./Domainfinder.py bioinformation.fasta 

MICE_8 gnl|CDD|256537 819 923gnl|CDD|260076 111 189gnl|CDD|260056 4 93
```

The program i created is almost to the required specification. * only have 3 problems that * need be to address:

1. there is an extra space between where I run the program and the result
2. my program does not write out the name of the sequence which has zero hits
3. my program does not separate the domain names by a space.

the correct output should look like this

```
mel@roswald:~$ ./Domainfinder.py bioinformation.fasta                                        
MICE_8 gnl|CDD|256537 819 923 gnl|CDD|260076 111 189 gnl|CDD|260056 4 93                                          
MICE_59
```

Comment: Should the second sequence (beginning with `>MICE_59` not be on its own line?
Also, this is python, so I suggest you look into the `print` command instead of sys.stdout, and look into string format notation (see tutorial [here](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: Thank you, the print command fixed a lot of the spacing issues. I ended up solving the problem. I do not know where this habit of using sys.stdout came from. You know my professor first name is Bryan honestly what a coincidence if you were him.

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue. Mainly what needed to be done is use a dictionary to hold the sequence names as keys instead of using lists. Than since dictionaries are random we need to be able to create a list from the dictionary to order the sequence names as they are read. Also we extract the sequence names from the rpsblast out. if anyone has any question feel free to pm.